# Autoenable maintenance mode in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.6. sometime my server goes down, sometimes webserver(apache2) is ok but mysql server is down. in that case while opening application its showing me errors and exception(in case of mysql server down). how can i activate maintenance mode automatically when such thing happen. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't activate maintenance mode when your server is down. Because when server is down it can't run PHP script.

For mysql you can create a middleware which checks your DB connection on each request and if it fails, you can use this.

```php
Artisan::call('down');
```

Or you can show custom created page which shows the "Site is down temporarily"